# Is inserting images now completely dead?

Tags: bug, images, imgur

After 'Browsing' an image, it does seem to upload, and the thumbnail appears (inside the Imgur box), but then 'Adding' returns to the text being edited without the image link being inserted. No markup code is generated at all.

Or am I doing something wrong?

The browser is Firefox 89.0, OS: Slackware-current64 (about three weeks old), no visible errors. As I reported, the image *does* upload, as a thumbnail appears in the upload dialog.

Nice one.

- I just tried to insert the image here (on Meta) and it *did* succeed.
- I still had the tag open on Stack Overflow, so I tried again there. No luck...
- I reloaded the page on Stack Overflow, and tried again, and yes, it did function properly now. So, ignorant me suspects there's either some way image uploading can get blocked during normal use, or the problem was solved in the meantime. (Note that I did several reloads when I originally detected the issue)

[image: Both protocols compared]

Comment: Which site are you trying this on? Which browser are you using? Does it work with extensions disabled? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Do you see a failed or blocked request there?

Comment: _“the_ image _does upload, as a thumbnail appears in the upload dialog”_ — That’s not the actual upload; that’s a temporary Blob URL from the provided file. Right-click and inspect the image. It’ll have a `src` starting with `blob:`, not an actual Imgur URL.

Comment: Ok... Looked at the network comm while clicking 'Add image' and there are no error message, as far as I can see. I haven't found how I can switch to the Alpha version to compare. I have previously published a few images without issue. I did update FF a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: The alpha editor is announced here: [Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](/q/360033/289905).

Comment: Do you have one or more of those? 1) Userscripts 2) Browser extensions 3) Ad blockers

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? Aren't veteran  users supposed to help  those who have a problem with the interface?

Comment: @Mari-LouA probably because the question lack(ed/s) details.

Comment: @Luuklag I see some details: Browser: FF, OS, which was added 10 hours previously, yet the post still attracted further DVs. Were it me, I wouldn't know what other information to add.

Comment: The picture is for a signal from an [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) [remote control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_control) (e.g., for a television).

Comment: Thus, it is likely for [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in both classic and Alpha editors

[image: Animated Gif of image upload in Alpha editor]

Alpha editor - this has no preview option

[image: Animated Gif of image upload in classic editor]

Classic editor, from Super User

Comment: Thanks for the animation. Just to be clear: That's exactly what I did, only the Markup code did not appear after clicking 'Add image'. Anyway, it works now, after today's reload of the page (see comments added in original post).